# Web API connection timeout

Tags: timeout, webapi, .net-7.0, connection-timeout

I have deployed .Net7 Web API on Windows Server 2019. Server is located in Netherlands.
When I was accessing my website and making a POST request using that API it was working perfectly.
Now I have relocated to Australia and from here when I make same POST request from same website in console it shows `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` after 21.04s. I guess it's because server is physically far away from me.

So what I want to do is to increase the request timeout for API.

I have added `Connection Timeout=120` to my connection string, but it doesn't seems to work.

Any other suggestions which I can try?